# kill a hung xterm

Tags: linux, terminal, kill, xterm

I used to rlogin/telnet a server and use `xterm&` to create several xterm sessions. But from time to time, the xterm may hang there and not responding at all(window can't be closed), leaving just a blank window.

I know the pid of all opened xterms from the 'mother xterm'. Is there any way to find out which is hanging one? I'd like to kill it immediately.

My environment is followed. I choose CDE as my desktop environment. Thanks!

Linux 2.6.9-67.ELsmp x86_64
OS:        RedHat Enterprise Linux 4.0 U6
xterm: X.Org 6.8.2(192)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try pressing <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>, you should get an X instead of your curser and it should kill whatever you click on. If the shortcut dosen't work run `xkill` from another terminal and the rest is the same.

Comment: Seems like it ought to be easy at first, but **CTRL+ALT+ESC** is a pretty tough one to do one-handed.

Comment: fantastic. I was stuck in the middle of `less`-ing a file. I could kill the `less` command, but it wouldn't do anything. And the parent shell couldn't be killed!  At last `xkill` the xterm did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`kill`](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/ukill.htm) command with `-9` like this:  `kill -9 pid`

Comment: is there any quick way to know the pid of hung xterm?

Answer (score 0):

Run xkill, click on the blank window.  Right click to cancel.